# Найти все простые числа в диапазоне [A; B]

Tags: c++, алгоритм, простые-числа

### Задача:

Найти все *простые* числа в диапазоне от А до В (**1 <= A <= B <= 10^12** ), при условии, что **В - А <= 10 ^ 6**. Уже 4 день ломаю над этим голову.
Есть решение на *С++* с помощью [Решета Эратосфена](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/eratosthenes_sieve).

### Решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

const ll MAXN = 1e6 + 1;

int main() {
    cin.tie(0); //Ускоряем cin
    cout.tie(0); //Ускоряем cout
    ll a, b;
    cin >> a >> b; //Получаем числа

    bool prime[MAXN], ans[MAXN]; //ans[i] - является ли число a + i простым
    memset(prime, true, MAXN);
    memset(ans, true, MAXN);
    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;

    //Оба вложенных цикла взяты из кода по ссылку (стандартная реализация решета Эратосфена)
    ll n = MAXN - 1;
    for (ll i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            ll r = a % i;
            r = (i - r) % i; //Что нужно прибавить к а, чтобы получить непростое число

            if (a + r > i && r < MAXN) //Проверяем на выход из массива. Если убрать условие а + r > i, тогда алгоритм отмечает 2, 3, 5 как не простые
                ans[r] = false;

            if (i + r < MAXN && a + r + i > 1ll * i)
                ans[i + r] = false;
            for (ll j = i * i; j <= n; j += i) {
                prime[j] = false;
                if (a <= j && j - a < MAXN) //Если а < 10 ^ 6 (бех этой проверки не работает)
                    ans[j - a] = false;
                if (j + r < MAXN)
                    ans[j + r] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Выводим результат
    for (ll i = 0; i <= b - a; ++i) {
        if (ans[i] && a + i >= 2)
            cout << a + i << ' ';
    }
}
```

### Описание решения:

Находим все простые на отрезке [0; b - a] за **О(10^6 log log 10^6)**, с помощью остатков от деления переносим эти простые на отрезок [a; b].

### Проблема:

Решение не работает на каких-то тестах (т.е *решение неполное*). Тесты, к сожалению, неизвестны.

Comment: советую почитать о [решете Аткина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) ([реализация на C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-atkin/))

Comment: @MaxU А как оно мне поможет? Представим, что b = 10 ^ 12, a = 10 ^ 12 - 10 ^ 6, тогда оно будет работать за (10 ^ 12) / log log (10 ^ 12) или примерно 10^12 / 6 (слишком долго)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начал проводить тесты на больших числах и заметил, что часто попадают 1-2 непростых. Не знаю почему, но замена `j = i * i` на `j = 2 * i` всё исправила, и программа не работала дольше 40 мс.

Полный код решения:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;

const ll MAXN = 1e6 + 1;
ll max(ll a, ll b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main() {
    //cin.tie(0); //Ускоряем cin
    //cout.tie(0); //Ускоряем cout
    ll a, b;
    cin >> a >> b; //Получаем числа

    bool prime[MAXN], ans[MAXN]; //ans[i] - является ли число a + i простым
    memset(prime, true, MAXN);
    memset(ans, true, MAXN);
    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;

    ll mmax = MAXN - 1;
    for (ll i = 2; i <= mmax; ++i) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            ll r = a % i;
            r = (i - r) % i; //Что нужно прибавить к а, чтобы получить непростое число

            if (a + r > i && r < MAXN) //Проверяем на выход из массива. Если убрать условие а + r > i, тогда алгоритм отмечает 2, 3, 5 как не простые
                ans[r] = false;

            if (i + r < MAXN && a + r + i > i)
                ans[i + r] = false;
            for (ll j = 2 * i; j <= mmax; j += i) {
                prime[j] = false;
                if (a <= j && j - a < MAXN) //Если а < 10 ^ 6 (бех этой проверки не работает)
                    ans[j - a] = false;
                if (j + r < MAXN) {
                    ans[j + r] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Выводим результат
    for (ll i = 0; i <= b - a; ++i) {
        if (ans[i] && a + i >= 2)
            cout << a + i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: А вот вместо введения своего алиаса типа `typedef long long ll;` лучше использовать стандартный `int64_t` (или в данном случае, лучше даже беззнаковый `uint64_t`) (эти типы общеупотребительны и становятся доступными при включении `<stdint.h>` (реально определяются в `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h`))

Comment: Замена `i * i` для больших чисел нужна из-за переполнения при умножении (результат не помещается в 64 бита, старшие теряются)